One angle in a triangle is twice the other. How to generalize the fact about its sides?
One angle in a triangle is twice the other. If I drop a perpendicular from the vertex of the third angle of the same triangle, then I suspect that the projection of the sides opposite to these angles on the line have the following properties:

If these angles are both acute, the difference of such projections is equal to the side opposite to the smaller angle (to prove it, just reflect this side over the constructed altitude and you get two isosceles triangles)
If the largest of these angles is right angle, then we have an isosceles right triangle (this is obvious because we then have $45-45-90$ triangle).
If the largest of these angles is obtuse angle, the sum of such projections is equal to the side opposite to the smaller angle (the proof is similar to the case when these angles are both acute).

Here are some demos I've sketched in GeoGebra for convenience.


Is there a well-established wording of this property? Is there a good generalization of it?

If you have learned about vectors this is simply $\overrightarrow{AB}\cdot\overrightarrow{AC} + \overrightarrow{AB}\cdot\overrightarrow{CB} = (\overrightarrow{AB})^2$

What I wanted to find is the formulation of this theorem in words, not vector identities :)

$AB = BD - AD$ if $\angle{CAB} > 90^\circ$ and $AB = BD + AD$ if $\angle{CAB} \leq 90^\circ$. Also this has nothing to do with $\angle CBA = \frac{\angle ABC}{2}$

This has nothing to do with the relation between the angles.

Here's a quick proof of this property in the acute-angle case (the other case is analogous). Let $\angle ABC=\alpha$ and $\angle BAC=2\alpha$. Drop altitude $CD$ and construct $F$ on $DB$ such that $DF=AD$. We have:
$$
\angle FCB=180°-3\alpha - (180°-4\alpha)=\alpha.
$$
Hence triangle $BFC$ is isosceles and:
$$
AC=CF=BF=BD-DF=BD-AD.
$$


Here is a slightly more economical presentation.  We have equality of angles $CAF=CFA$.  Meanwhile, $CFA= FCB+FBC$.  Therefore $FCB=2\alpha-\alpha=\alpha$.

My question was whether there are generalizations of this property; I know its proof (as said in the question), but it's absolutely great to see the proof! The only thought I had is, like, what if we take angles $\alpha$ and $2^k\alpha$, so that $0 < \alpha < 2^k\alpha < \pi$.

@Rusurano With angles $\alpha$ and $k\alpha$ you can repeat $k-1$ times the above construction. But you won't get a "nice" result, I'm afraid.
